# MySites URL - use another query paramater other than accountname? GUID? | SP 2013

Tags: url, query, guid, mysite, parameter

Is it possible to use a different query parameter other than accountname for Mysites?  For example, can we use the GUID to link a person to the person.aspx page?

The problem is that because the accountname is displayed in the URL, we don’t want users browsing to other users' sites and discovering this piece of information.

Perhaps we can hide the query string if it’s not possible to use another query parameter?

Perhaps we can use VB to do something custom here?

Appreciate any suggestions.